# Fetch not working on react native when run on Expo from iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, fetch, expo

So it's actually been on and off the past few days, the fetch function for POST method (for login purposes) on my app would suddenly stop working when I'm not even making any changes to the code.
I spent hrs tracking down the bug the first time this happened but realized that the code is still running fine on Android simulator that I run from Android studio.
This problem only happens on my iphone device when I run the code via expo.

is there any sort of convention on how to tackle this issue?
I've been googling for a few days now but no one forum actually agreed on a solution, some works but says it's unstable and some just doesn't work.

I'm pretty new to expo, react native, and everything in general, so please enlighten me using "english" lol

EDIT: since I was asked about the code, here it is, I hope it helps:

```
export function login(user, callback){
  var endpoint = "oauth/token";
  const { username, password } = user;

  //from https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-encode-and-decode-strings-with-base64-in-javascript
  var Base64={_keyStr:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",encode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i,s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=Base64._utf8_encode(e);while(f<e.length){n=e.charCodeAt(f++);r=e.charCodeAt(f++);i=e.charCodeAt(f++);s=n>>2;o=(n&3)<<4|r>>4;u=(r&15)<<2|i>>6;a=i&63;if(isNaN(r)){u=a=64}else if(isNaN(i)){a=64}t=t+this._keyStr.charAt(s)+this._keyStr.charAt(o)+this._keyStr.charAt(u)+this._keyStr.charAt(a)}return t},decode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i;var s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9+/=]/g,"");while(f<e.length){s=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));o=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));u=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));a=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));n=s<<2|o>>4;r=(o&15)<<4|u>>2;i=(u&3)<<6|a;t=t+String.fromCharCode(n);if(u!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(r)}if(a!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(i)}}t=Base64._utf8_decode(t);return t},_utf8_encode:function(e){e=e.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");var t="";for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++){var r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r)}else if(r>127&&r<2048){t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6|192);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}else{t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>12|224);t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6&63|128);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}}return t},_utf8_decode:function(e){var t="";var n=0;var r=c1=c2=0;while(n<e.length){r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r);n++}else if(r>191&&r<224){c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&31)<<6|c2&63);n+=2}else{c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);c3=e.charCodeAt(n+2);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&15)<<12|(c2&63)<<6|c3&63);n+=3}}return t}};

  let header = {
              "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
              "Authorization": ("Basic " + Base64.encode(username+":"+password))
            };
  let userData = {
                    "grant_type": "password",
                    "username": username,
                    "password": password
                 };

  return fetchAPI(endpoint,'POST', header, userData)
  .then((tokenJson) => {
      alert("\nAccess Token:\n\n" + tokenJson.access_token + "");
      callback(true, {exists : true, token : tokenJson.access_token}, null);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    alert(error);
      callback(false, null, error);
  });
}
```

And here's the fetchAPI function (a generic fetch function) called from that function:

```
export function fetchAPI(endpoint, method, header, data) {
 let url = 'http://10.64.2.149:8081/' + endpoint;

 let options = {
        method: method,
        headers: header,
        body: stringify(data) //from qs-stringify package
      };

 return fetch(url, options)
    .then(response => {
        return response.json()
            .then((json) => { ...//not relevant from this point on
```

The fetch 'POST' seems to always get stuck at `response.json()`, it just never resolves until it returns `"network request failed"`. But as I said only happens sometimes when I run it on iphone via expo. It is fine on Android sim.

Thanks! :)

Comment: What is your server URL? https protocol or http?

Comment: I'd be helpful to include the code so we can further help.

Comment: here's the code, hope it helps! sorry I didnt make it clear the first time I thought this was common issue with the combination of fetch, expo and ios. thanks again!